# Since two particles can be paired can we use them for instant communication?

Tags: particle-physics

I saw that particles can be paired and that no matter the distance what one does so does the other. Now, can we put each particle into a magnetic field where we could manipulate the spin? If you make the particle spin up zero or down for one and the other field detects the spin change you could have an instant communication device for probes and astronauts.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light_communication and you will probably find duplicates of your question on this website.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. Entanglement only means, for example, that coupled particles have opposite (but unknown) spins at the time of the entenglement's creation. Manipulating one of them does not change the state of the other, so transmitting information this way is impossible.